# Enum inheriting from int

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, enums

I've found this all over the place in this code:

```
public enum Blah: int
{
    blah = 0,
    blahblah = 1
}
```

Why would it need to inherit from int? Does it ever need to?

Comment: By the way, that's a backing type, not inheritance.

Comment: Some people just love to type more stuff to get default behavior. I call them "this-ers".

Comment: @keke: It'd be better to call them "private-ers".  There are times when you _need_ to write `this.`, but you **EDIT**: almost _never_ need to write `private`.

Comment: @keke: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349269/does-c-need-the-private-keyword

Comment: Though it sound redundant in this case but you should also look through your whole code base where a different backing type has been provided while declaring an enum. Other backing types like byte, Int16, Int32 (or int ) , Int64 (long) are also possible. Just imagine in this particular case you are using 4 bytes of RAM memory just to save ONE BIT of information. You should certainly change it to byte. Byte can easily contain 256 different integer values from 0 to 255 which suffices for most enum based scenarios. In high end hardware we don't care about this thing but as a programmer we should.

Comment: @heisenberg but if - let's say - we make assignment in a constuctor, putting "this" before field name easily shows it's an instance level field... :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> Every enumeration type has an
>   underlying type, which can be any
>   integral type except char. The default
>   underlying type of the enumeration
>   elements is int.

So, no, you don't need to use int. It would work with any integral type. If you don't specify any it would use int as default and it's this type that will be used to store the enumeration into memory.

Answer (score 14):

Enums are implicitly backed by integers.
`: int` just restates the default, just like `void M();` vs. `private void M();`.

You can also create enums that are backed by other intergral types, such as `enum GiantEnum : long`.

Comment: I am just curious is it possible the find a definition of the `backing` anywhere? I feel that I understand it somehow, but I would like to check the correctness of my understanding.

Comment: @qqqqqqq: CTRL + F `: ushort` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to, it's implied. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> An enumeration is a set of named constants whose underlying type is any integral type except Char. If no underlying type is explicitly declared, Int32 is used. Enum is the base class for all enumerations in the .NET Framework.

This means you could use`byte`, `sbyte`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, or `ulong`.

Also, setting the values the way you have described (blah=0, blahblah=1), while redundant, is OK, since, according to the [C# Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc)

> If the declaration of the enum member has no initializer, its associated value is set implicitly, as follows:
>
> • If the enum member is the first enum member declared in the enum type, its associated value is zero.
>
> • Otherwise, the associated value of the enum member is obtained by increasing the associated value of the textually preceding enum member by one. This increased value must be within the range of values that can be represented by the underlying type, otherwise a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 4):

`int` is by default the type of any `enum`. It does not need to be declared explicitly.

It's more useful when you want to use something else (`byte`, `long`, and friends).

Answer (score 1):

You don't **need** to inherit from `int` but by default it does.  You *can* inherit from other integral types (`byte`, `long`, etc) if you want to.  An example would be if you wanted to save memory or column space in a DB.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I don’t care if an enum is signed or unsigned, or how many bits it has, so I just let the system use it’s default that is int.

However there are times when I do care that the enum is a signed 32 bit int, and then it is good to make it clear that I do care.   I would expect a comment as well spelling out **why** I care.

Answer (score -1):

it gives it a numeric value, that is all, as far as i know

Comment: No, it already has a numeric value. If you don't specify a backing type, it's `int` by default, so specifying `int` doesn't give it anything that it doesn't already have.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to inherit as the base type of an Enum is by default, int.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032(v=vs.71).aspx

```
base-type (Optional)
The underlying type that specifies the storage allocated for each enumerator. It can be one of the integral types except char. The default is int.
```

Answer (score -1):

An enum "member" can have an underlying "value".  The inheritance from int tells you what type the value will take.