# Does C# need the private keyword?

Tags: c#, keyword, language-lawyer

(inspired by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348924/enum-inheriting-from-int#comment7429503_6348924))

Is there ever a situation in which you *need* to use the `private` keyword?
(In other words, a situation in which omitting the keyword would result in different behavior)

Comment: I've deleted my answer as it turns out you can't have a private delegate at the namespace scope.

Comment: Exactly.  A `private` non-nested type doesn't make any sense; it would be the same as `internal`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Bar { get; private set; }
}
```

Omitting the word 'private' would change the accessibility.

Comment: Correct.  I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Note that this feature (mixed-visibility accessors) is new to C# 2.0

Comment: @SLaks: Of course, C# 2.0 shipped six years ago, so "new to C# 2.0" is a bit of an oxymoron. Mixed-accessibility in a property has been a feature of the language for a long time now.

Comment: @Eric: True.  I was wondering whether `private` is ever needed in C# 1.

Comment: Interestingly, when applying an access modifyer to an accessor (getter/setter) in a property or indexer, you **restrict** the accessibility of that getter/setter, compared to what it would have been without the modifyer. In all other cases in C#, specifying an access modifyer to a member **relaxes** the access to that member (because the default without any access modifyer is the most restricted access possible).

Comment: @EricLippert The other situation where deleting a `private` keyword also matters (se my new answer) is also "new" to C# 2. And now it is eight years ago that version shipped, if I increment your year count correctly. The conjecture by SLaks that the keyword could _always_ be omitted in C# 1 still stands.

Answer (score 8):

> a situation in which omitting the keyword [`private`] would result in different behavior

David Yaw's answer gave the most usual situation. Here is another one:

In `Account_generated.cs`:

```
// Generated file. Do not edit!

public partial class Account
{
  ...

  private partial class Helper
  {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

In `AccountHandCoded.cs`:

```
public partial class Account
{
  ...

  public partial class Helper
  {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

The above code will not compile. The first "part" of `Account` ***requires*** the nested class `Helper` to be `private`. Therefore the attempt by the hand-coder to make `Helper` public must fail!

However, had the first part of the class simply omitted the `private` keyword, all would compile.

So for `partial` classes (and structs, interfaces), the access-level-free declaration

```
partial class Name
```

means "the other 'parts' of this class are allowed to decide what the accessibility should be".

Whereas explicitly giving the default accessibility (which is `internal` for non-nested types and `private` for nested ones) means "this class must have the most restricted access possible, and the other 'parts' cannot change that fact".

Answer (score 1):

`private` isn't about the runtime behaviour. It's to make your application maintainable. What's hidden by `private` can only ever affect the code outside its class through the `public` or `protected` members.

So the answer is 'no' for runtime behaviour, 'yes' for developer behaviour!

Comment: the question seems to be more about the fact that if you omit the access modifier entirely, it almost always results in `private` access by default. As the two answers posting now suggest, though; it's only 'almost'.

Answer (score 1):

In C# version 7.2 and later.

The `private protected` keyword combination is a member access modifier. A private protected member is accessible by types derived from the containing class, but only within its containing assembly.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private-protected