# Partial classes and access modifier issue

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers, partial-classes

According to [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) for partial classes :

> All the parts must have the same accessibility, such as **public**, **private**, and so on.

but if you create a WindowsForm application, you will have the default Form class in two partial classes.

The code behind :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ...
}
```

and the designer :

```
partial class Form1
{
    ...
}
```

Access modifiers are different, but it will compile.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't specify the access modifier in a part of a partial class, it uses the same access modifier as the other part.

---

Relevant part from the C# 5 spec: §10.2.2

> When a partial type declaration includes an accessibility specification (the public, protected, internal, and private modifiers) it must agree with all other parts that include an accessibility specification. If no part of a partial type includes an accessibility specification, the type is given the appropriate default accessibility (§3.5.1).

So the spec says that the accessibility must agree with other parts *if it is specified*; in other words, it doesn't have to be specified in every part. The wording could probably be changed to be less ambiguous, though...

Comment: I think so, but its against the quoted documentation.

Comment: No, that's not against the documentation. The other part is `public`, even if it doesn't say so. Try making the other part `private`, and you'll see. Remember there is only one class, with many parts. A single class has a single accessibility.

Comment: @NaserAsadi Not really. The documentation states that all parts must *have* the same accessibility, not that they must *explicitly declare* the same accessibility. In the code you posted, the two classes do have the same accessibility (albeit implicit).

Comment: @NaserAsadi, I quoted the relevant part of the spec in my answer.

Comment: @John Saunders and @dcastro:class access modifires are `internal` and `public` and `internal` is the default. So, I don't think so.

Comment: @NaserAsadi the spec says essentially that the default applies only if *none of the parts has a modifier.*  If any part has a modifier, then that is the class's accessibility.  However, if parts have conflicting modifiers, that is a compile error.

Comment: @NaserAsadi I once wrote an [answer on omitting `private`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18768294/1336654) which was a bit related.