# How int is the backing type for enum

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, enums, integer

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348924/enum-inheriting-from-int) post `int` is the backing type for `enum`.

When I check the source code of .NET [System.Enum](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,36729210e317a805) abstract class inherits from [System.ValueType](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,915ba3e46633f948) abstract class.

But when I check the [System.Int32](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs,225942ed7b7a3252) struct it inherits from interfaces but not from [System.ValueType](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,915ba3e46633f948).

On the contrary, when I decompile **mscorlib.dll** and check the `Int32` struct it says that the struct has base type of `System.ValueType`.

[image]

But still checking the decompiled source code I can not see anything about `System.ValueType`.

[image]

It makes me think that the `struct` keyword makes the declaration auto-Sytem.ValueType, which Microsoft also denotes in this [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4.aspx).

But I still have a question. As far as I know, inheritance of two different classes from the same parent does not imply that one also inherits from other. I mean if `B:A` and `C:A` this does not always mean that `C:B`.

Also, when I check the source code, `System.Enum` has quite a different implementation to that of `System.Int32`.

So, under these circumstances, how does this fit with 'System.Int32' being the backing type for `System.Enum`?

Can anyone explain?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3504145/1625737

Comment: "All value types are derived **implicitly** from the System.ValueType." (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much @haim770. Those references were quite useful. Especially StackOverflow post was top of the notch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Int32 is just the default underlying type for enum, however this is changeable.  You can change this by specifying a different datatype e.g.

```
enum ExampleEnum : byte
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
};
```

---

Here is what Microsoft says regarding the enum:

> Every enumeration type has an underlying type, which can be **any integral type** except char.
>   The default underlying type of enumeration elements is int.
>   To declare an enum of another integral type, such as byte, use a colon after the identifier followed by the type,
>   ...
>   The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

^ [Source MSDN: enum (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

You're confusing `enum` (the C# keyword to define an enumeration type) and `Enum` (the class that such an enumeration type derives from).

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

enum Foo { A, B, C };

static class Program {
  static void Main() {
    foreach (var field in typeof(Foo).GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
      Console.WriteLine("Found instance field \"" + field.Name + "\" of type \"" + field.FieldType.FullName + "\"");
  }
}
```

On my system, this prints

```
Found instance field "value__" of type "System.Int32"
```

This is because `Foo` is effectively defined as (pseudo-code, not valid C#)

```
struct Foo : Enum {
  int value__;
}
```

along with some extra compiler support, some extra static fields to list the enum's members, but the basic idea remains the same.

The backing type is defined as part of each concrete enumeration type, not as part of `System.Enum`. It couldn't be, because it may be different for two distinct enumeration types.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting unstuck because of the difference between **inheritance** and **representation**.

Just because `B` inherits from `A` it doesn't mean that `B` is represented (backed) by `A`.

An `Enum` can inherit from `ValueType`, but be represented (backed) by `int`.

It's a bit like a `Person` class can inherit from `Object` by it uses `string` (Name) and `int` (Age) as the backing types for the class.

The important, fundamental thing, is that the compiler does a bit of magic when dealing with a number of types. `ValueType` inherits from `Object` but it isn't a reference type because the compiler deals with it specially.

An `Enum` is a special `ValueType` that has an automatically created backing-type - `int` by default - and that's all up to the compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts @Enigmativity.

Answer (score 1):

`int` and `enum` are two very different things, for examples you can calculate (add/subtract) with integers, which you can't do with enums. So it is clear that the impelmentation of both is very different.

Still an enum is **stored** the same way as an integer (usually a 32 Bit memory location) and there is a 1:1 conversion between enum values and int values.

In this sense int is a *backing type* for an enum.